# Changing a global variable to a window.prompt() variable within a .click function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, web-deployment-project

I'm currently working on [The Odin Project's first project in their curriculum](http://www.theodinproject.com/web-development-101/javascript-and-jquery?ref=lnav).

For step 4, I am trying to create a window.prompt() that will ask the user for a new number to assign to a pre-existing global variable like so:

```
var gridSize;
var gridAmount;

    if (gridAmount === "", null, undefined, false || gridAmount < 1 ||gridAmount > 64 || isNaN(gridAmount)){
            var gridSize = 16;
        } else {
            var gridSize = gridAmount;
        };

    function grid() {

        for (var x = 0; x < gridSize; x++) {
            $('#container').append("<div class='grid'></div>");
            $('.grid').height(800 / gridSize);
        };
        for (var x = 0; x < gridSize; x++) {
            $('.grid').append("<div class='row'></div>")
            $('.row').width(800 / gridSize);
            $('.row').height(800 / gridSize);
        };
    };

    $('#reset-squares').click(function(){
        location.reload(true);
        var gridAmount = window.prompt("From 1 to 64, what is your grid's parameters (00 x 00)?");
    });
```

What I am trying to do is reset the page, then assign the variable `gridAmount` to a new number defined in the .click() function.  Am I missing something?  Is this unachievable with the current code structure?

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jsadams27/ypbhy013/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Take the **var** in front of *gridAmount* out of the function.

The first **var gridAmount** is creating a global variable.  If you assign a new value to it in the function, it will update the global variable.

Adding the **var** in the function creates a variable local to the function with the same name, so the global variable is not updated.

Also checkout jQuery's **.empty** and **.destroy** methods.  They will allow you to ready the HTML for the next run of the code.

Comment: I tried this in my demo and personal files and it still returns the same problem.  I think it might have more to do with the reloading function preventing my new variable from being reassigned.

Comment: Remove the **var**s from the gridSIzes as well - you should only declare global variables once.  And the location.reload

Answer (score 1):

`gridAmount`
is your global right? and you want to assign the value of the prompt into it?

```
gridAmount = window.prompt("From 1 to 64, what is your grid's parameters (00 x 00)?");
```

just remove the var when assigning new value...

Answer (score 0):

You're right in thinking it may not be possible.  The page is reloading before the `gridAmount` can ever be set.

You need to pass the value back to the page and set it before you reload the page.

You could reload the page with a query string `?show_prompt=true` (or one that contains a value you need etc.) for example.

Then you would be able to check if that was set when the page loads / reloads and show the prompt, get the value from the user and set that to `var gridAmount` at the top of the script.